# Flutter app not showing any output on dartpad

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to see how it looks when my flutter app gets run on a device. On flutter's website, this seems to be possible. However, when I access dartpad.dartlang.org and try to run my app there, it shows nothing. Is there a way to make it work like that of flutter's website?

Im on pop os, based on debian linux. Accessing dartpad within firefox browser

Comment: If you open the Samples menu from the top-right corner of Dartpad and choose Counter, does that work for you?

Comment: nope, It displays nothing @jamesdlin

Comment: Does non-Flutter Dart code work in Dartpad for you?  Do you have any JavaScript-blocking extensions enabled?  Have you tried using a clean Firefox profile?

Comment: Yes. Non flutter code works perfectly. I use adguard adblocker on chrome(I switched from firefox btw) and it is the only extension I use, I don't think that would be the reason.